# Unable to reach host from dockerized CentOS through OpenVPN proxy

Tags: docker, openvpn

I am using Windows with CentOS in a docker container. I am already connected to VPN using open-vpn in Windows. But, when I try to reach one host from dockerized CentOS, it says unable to connect.

Is it possible to reach to that host from CentOS?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do here? Any commands you tried out to access the "host" (be more descriptive than 'host') will help us get a clearer picture of what you what to ask.

Comment: Try reaching out to the host machine using the hostname `docker.for.win.localhost` and see if helps

Comment: @DhruvanGanesh Actually, i am doing gradle build in docker container. When i am doing gradle build, it connects to our repo and downloads the required libraries to local. My build is failing continuously as it would not able connect to remote repo, i just checked using `curl`. It is failing.

Comment: @SubhabrataMondal I've updated my answer, my guess is that gradle is not picking up your proxy settings. Use ENV (dockerfile) or --env (docker run) to set your proxy

Answer (score 1):

From what I've gathered from your question, you should definitely follow both the steps mentioned below:

You will be using Bridge Network Driver by default and you might not need be concerned with Step 1. I've mentioned this in case you were experimenting with the default settings.

1. Use Bridge Network / Host Network drivers for your Docker Container to get access to your host machine's (which is running the docker containers) network. Go through https://docs.docker.com/network/ for more info.
2. Configure docker proxy. Add your vpn settings in the files mentioned in https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/ as per your use case.

Short Version:

Add the following to your Dockerfile or their equivalent in case you use `docker run` to execute your builds. For more info refer to the link in Step 2.

```
ENV HTTP_PROXY "proxy"
ENV HTTPS_PROXY "proxy"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe SELinux prevents connecting to the VPN. You can check the log messages with following command:

```
cat /var/log/messages | grep "SELinux is preventing"
```

If log messages show SELinux is involved in the problem, to ensure that only SELinux is in charge, go to `/etc/selinux/config` and edit the line `SELINUX=enforcing` in this way:

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

and restart CentOS. This causes SELinux only generate log messages without enforcing the policies. If the problem solves, you should create appropriate SELinux policies regarding the log messages that tell which restrictions prevent connecting to the VPN. Your custom policies must provide required permissions. Then you can revert your change in the above file and restart CentOS to leverage SELinux security along with accessing the VPN.

Also you can check the permissions of *.pem files associated to open-vpn using the following command:

```
ls -l /home/some-user/.cert/nm-openvpn/
```

for user 'some-user' or

```
ls -l /root/.cert/nm-openvpn/
```

for user 'root'.